# How Do I add dependency for Java?

Tags: java, jar

I'm very new to Java. I have a single class file which is used to do some processing.

That class file is depended on a `jar`. I'm very new to Java, where I'm passing the `jar`  to my classpath while running the program:

```
javac -classpath jar MyProgram.java
```

Now I wish to bundle both the `jar` and `MyProgram` into separate jar with dependency resolved.

Are there any ways to do this in Java? Note that it my `MyProgram` java is only around 50 lines of code, so some simple solution will be good.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot put the library JAR inside another JAR file - Java will not be able to load classes from embedded JAR files.

You could create a JAR file containing just the classes of your application, and have the library JAR alongside it. See [Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) for details on how to do this exactly.

If you really want everything to be in a single JAR file, you could use a tool such as [One-JAR](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) to package it.

Answer (score 3):

You should not bundle both your compiled code and the dependency in a separate jar. You should bundle only your compiled classes in a jar and when running the program, you put both your jar and the dependency in the classpath.

Use the jar command to build your jar file and then use the command below to run your program:

```
java -classpath dependecy.jar;yourjar.jar MyProgram
```

Comment: Packaging the compiled classes with jar results a jar file indeed. See the docs for the jar command for learning how to use it.

Comment: So the dependency will be resolved between `MyProgram` and `jar`?

Comment: The classpath will contain the 2 jar files, so all the classes inside will be visible to the class loader.